# Form does not return validation messages using CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my `HunterModel.php` file all the validations and custom messages are from the validations, **but I don't know if my `form_create.php` doesn't show the error messages, they simply return to the form without shows the failures committed by the user**, why is this happening?

- `form_create.php`

```
    <?php if (isset($validation)) : ?>
      <div class="text-danger">
        <?= $validation->listErrors() ?>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <form action="<?= site_url('create')?>" method="POST">
                ...
    </form>
```

In my `HunterController.php` method `createHunter()` must do the record insertion operation, checking if everything is right or returns to the form showing the necessary corrections to the user.

- `HunterController.php`

```
    public function createHunter()
    {
        try {
            helper(['form']);
            $hunter = new HunterModel();
            $data = [
                'name_hunter' => $this->request->getPost('name_hunter'),
                'age_hunter' => $this->request->getPost('age_hunter'),
                'height_hunter' => $this->request->getPost('height_hunter'),
                'weight_hunter' => $this->request->getPost('weight_hunter'),
                'type_hunter' => $this->request->getPost('type_hunter'),
                'type_nen' => $this->request->getPost('type_nen'),
                'type_blood' => $this->request->getPost('type_blood')
            ];
            if ($hunter->insert($data)){
                return $this->response->redirect(site_url('listing'));       
            } else {
                $data['validation'] = $this->validator;
                echo view('form_create', $data);
            }    
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

- `HunterModel.php`

```
        // Validation
        protected $validationRules      = [
            'nome_hunter' => 'required|max_length[30]',
            'idade_hunter' => 'required|integer',
            'altura_hunter' => 'required|decimal',
            'peso_hunter' => 'required|decimal',
            'tipo_hunter' => 'required|max_length[30]',
            'tipo_nen' => 'required|max_length[30]',
            'tipo_sanguineo' => 'required|max_length[3]'
        ];
        protected $validationMessages   = [
            'nome_hunter' => [
                'required' => 'O nome do Hunter não pode ficar vazio.',
                'max_length' => 'O nome do Hunter precisa ter no máximo 30 caracteres.'
            ],
            'idade_hunter' => [
                'required' => 'A idade do Hunter não pode ficar vazia.',
                'integer' => 'A idade do Hunter precisa ser um número inteiro.'
            ],
            'peso_hunter' => [
                'required' => 'O peso do Hunter não pode ficar vazio.',
                'decimal' => 'O peso do Hunter precisa ser um número decimal.'
            ],
            'altura_hunter' => [
                'required' => 'A altura do Hunter não pode ficar vazia.',
                'decimal' => 'A altura do Hunter precisa ser um número decimal.'
            ],
            'tipo_hunter' => [
                'required' => 'É necessário definir o tipo de Hunter.',
                'max_length' => 'O tipo de Hunter precisa ter no máximo 30 caracteres.'
            ],
            'tipo_nen' => [
                'required' => 'É necessário definir o nen do Hunter.',
                'max_length' => 'O nen do Hunter precisa ter no máximo 30 caracteres.'
            ],
            'tipo_sanguineo' => [
                'required' => 'É necessário definir o tipo sanguíneo do Hunter.',
                'max_length' => 'O tipo sanguíneo do Hunter precisa ter no máximo 3 caracteres.'
            ]
        ];
```

Comment: _"In my HunterModel.php file all the validations and custom messages are from the validations"_ - You're not fetching any validation messages from the `HunterModel` though? The only reference to any validation in your code is `$data['validation'] = $this->validator;`, but `$this->validator` refers to the controller, not the model. Where are you validating the form data using that validator instance?

Comment: @M.Eriksson I didn't quite understand what you said.

Comment: There's nothing in your code that suggests that you're actually validating anything. The only thing you're doing is passing `$this->validator` to the view. No idea what that property contains though. And what does `$this->validator` have to do with your `HunterModel`-class, where you say the validation happens in? Where are you actually fetching any possible validation messages from the `HunterModel`-class?

Answer (score 1):

you should learning again about validate data,
learn this page
https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/validation.html#form-validation-tutorial

if you want to use helper function, try this

```
function yourController($request){
helper(['form']);
$validation =  \Config\Services::validation();
 $rules = [
            "nome_hunter" => [
                "label" => "nome_hunter", 
                "rules" => 'required|max_length[30]',
            ]
        ];

        if ($this->validate($rules)) {

            $hunter = new HunterModel();
            
            $hunter->insert($data)
            $session = session();
            $session->setFlashData("success", "Successful");
            return redirect()->to('/');
        } else {
            $data["validation"] = $validation->getErrors();
        }
}
```

or you can make the validation on your controller, don't make it on model

you can try this too
[how to validate form data in codeigniter 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62897545/how-to-validate-form-data-in-codeigniter-4)